# About Web Scraping and missing data

Tags: python, web-scraping, missing-data, review

I am trying to scrape some data from yelp page. However, some values are missing when I get the result and the missing data alters every time when I execute the code( E.g : At first execution 2 data are missing, at second execution 1 data is missing). Do you guys know why this happens? Thank you!!

```
import time
review_listings= []
cols2 = ['restaurant name','username','ratings','review.text']


copy = 0
for url in data_rev['url']:  # Each url has 20 so start 
    start = time.time()
    for p in pages:
        url_review = url+ "&start={}".format(str(p))
        page = r.get(url_review)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
        res_name = soup.find("h1",{"class":"lemon--h1__373c0__2ZHSL heading--h1__373c0___56D3 undefined heading--inline__373c0__1jeAh"}).text
        tables=soup.findAll('li',{'class':'lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-b3__373c0__342DA border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU'})
        if(len(tables) == 0):
            
            print(url_review)
            break
        else:
            
            for table in tables:
                #name,ratings,username:
                username = table.find("span",{"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G text__373c0__2Kxyz fs-block text-color--blue-dark__373c0__1jX7S text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--bold__373c0__1elNz"}).a.text
                ratings = table.find("span",{"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__3JqBP border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"}).div.get("aria-label")
                text = table.find("span",{"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G raw__373c0__3rKqk"}).text
                review_listings.append([res_name,username,ratings,text])
              
            rev_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(review_listings,columns=cols2)
            
    size_df = len(rev_df)
    
    print("review sizes are =>",size_df - copy)

    print(res_name)
    copy = size_df
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: could you share some example `url` ?

Comment: https://www.yelp.com/biz/saku-vancouver-3?adjust_creative=6UfDTLB2kPgTVIhuA-U8mg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=6UfDTLB2kPgTVIhuA-U8mg

Comment: @user14245642 use `Selenium` instead of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I thought about that too but I have to scrape more than thousands of data, so it will take too long if I use Selenium.

Comment: High chances that the classes you use are dynamic to avoir scraping

Comment: You see the `api_v3_blabla` text in the link? Seems links are endpoint and they return json response. You can just send request using endpoints and process json. No need to bs4 or selenium

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all the data you're interested in is stored as `json` in the page source. This could be a more reliable way to grab informations from this page:

```
import re
import json
import requests

## Using headers is always a good pratice
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/saku-vancouver-3', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

# Lets find the 'script' tag which contains restaurant's information
data_tag = soup.find('script',text = re.compile('"@type":'))

#Load it properly as json
data = json.loads(data_tag.text)

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
{'@context': 'https://schema.org',
'@type': 'Restaurant',
'name': 'Saku',
'image': 'https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/_TjVeAVRczn0yITxvBqrCA/l.jpg',
'priceRange': 'CA$11-30',
'telephone': '',
'address': {'streetAddress': '548 W Broadway',
'addressLocality': 'Vancouver',
'addressCountry': 'CA',
'addressRegion': 'BC',
'postalCode': 'V5Z 1E9'},
'review': [{'author': 'Jackie L.',
  'datePublished': '1970-01-19',
  'reviewRating': {'ratingValue': 5},
  'description': 'With restaurants .... }
  ...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it gives me an error : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You tested it with the url you provided me? If so, it could be that your IP is temporarly blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the restaurant name, all the name of the reviewers, their reviews, ratings across multiple pages. Of course if you haven't been blocked by that site already.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/XAH2HpuUUtu7CUO26pbs4w/review_feed?'

params = {
    'rl': 'en',
    'sort_by': 'relevance_desc',
    'q': '',
    'start': ''
}

page = 0

while True:
    params['start'] = page
    res = requests.get(url,params=params)
    if not res.json()['reviews']:break
    for item in res.json()['reviews']:
        restaurant = item['business']['name']
        rating = item['rating']
        user = item['user']['markupDisplayName']
        review = item['comment']['text']
        print(restaurant,rating,user,review)

    page+=20
```

Comment: Did you try the script @user14245642?